# Rails - Model.all.to_json doesn't put all Devise attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, model, attributes

I am trying to save all information from database table to JSON, like this:

```
File.open("tmp/users.json", 'wb') {|file| file << User.all.to_json }
```

The problem is, that in the hash are missing these columns:

```
t.string   "encrypted_password",       :default => "",   :null => false
t.string   "reset_password_token"
t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
t.datetime "remember_created_at"
t.integer  "sign_in_count",            :default => 0
t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
```

All these columns comes from the **Devise** gem.
How to add them to the final JSON file?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

attr_accessible has been removed from Rails 4.

Nevertheless, I suggest you to override the as_json method to get it working.

```
def as_json(options=nil)
  attrs = {
    only: [
      :id,
      :email,
      :confirmed_at,
      :locked_at
    ],
    methods: [:roles_list]
  }
  super (attrs.merge(options || {}))
end
```

Nevertheless, I think that the best option is to use the ActiveModel::Serializer (https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers).

Comment: Great answer ! The gem can be an overkill sometimes though.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the attributes you'd like to see in your JSON to the whitelisted attr_accessible attributes for that model.

For example:

```
attr_accessible :last_sign_in_at, :current_sign_in_at
```

If you're uncomfortable with that option, you can override as_json for the model, like so:

```
def as_json(options={})
  options["last_sign_in_at"] ||= self.last_sign_in_at
  super(options)
end
```